# Laravel Testing: Is this testing too much of the inner workings?

Tags: php, unit-testing, php5, laravel, phpunit

So I'm using laravel for a project and have a `InvoiceRepository` and a `InvoiceRepositoryTest` and I have written the test first for the first time. But I'm not sure if this test is ideal so I wanted to ask if it's a good test or if it needs improving. I'm a bit uncertain if I'm not testing too much of the inner workings of the method.

For example `$this->model->where('order_id', $order->id)` could also be written as `$this->model->whereOrderId($order->id)` but that would do the exact same thing but make the test fail. Also I need a lot of Laravel's internal classes to make the test pass.

Also the `Factory` class is from the [JeffreyWay/Laravel-Test-Helpers package](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-Test-Helpers) and used to create model instances with some data populated.

So here is the method from the repository:

```
public function createUserInvoice(\Order $order)
{
    if ($order->status !== 'sent')
    {
        throw new InvoiceRepositoryException('Cannot create user invoice if the order status is not `sent`');
    }

    $collection = $this->model->where('order_id', $order->id)
                              ->whereNotNull('user_id')
                              ->get();

    if ( ! $collection->isEmpty())
    {
        throw new InvoiceRepositoryException('Cannot create duplicate user invoice. There already exists a user invoice for the given order');
    }

    $invoiceData = array(
        'order_id'         => $order->id,
        'user_id'          => $order->user_id,
        'from_name'        => InvoiceRepository::OUR_NAME,
        'from_address'     => InvoiceRepository::OUR_ADDRESS,
        'from_postal_code' => InvoiceRepository::OUR_POSTAL_CODE,
        'from_city'        => InvoiceRepository::OUR_CITY,
        'from_email'       => InvoiceRepository::OUR_EMAIL,
        'from_vat'         => InvoiceRepository::OUR_VAT,
        'to_name'          => $order->customer_name,
        'to_address'       => $order->customer_invoice_address,
        'to_postal_code'   => $order->customer_invoice_postal_code,
        'to_city'          => $order->customer_invoice_city,
        'to_email'         => $order->customer_email,
        'total'            => $order->total
    );

    $this->model->validateException($invoiceData);

    $invoice = $this->model->create($invoiceData);

    $invoiceItems = [];

    foreach($order->items as $item)
    {
        $invoiceItems[] = new InvoiceItem(array(
            'invoice_id'  => $invoice->id,
            'description' => $item->product_code ? $item->product_name . ' (' . $item->product_code . ')' : $item->product_name,
            'quantity'    => $item->quantity,
            'price'       => $item->price
        ));
    }

    $invoice->items()->saveMany($invoiceItems);

    return $invoice;
}
```

And here are 3 test methods and the testcase setUp method:

```
public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();

    $this->order = Factory::make('\Order', ['id' => 666]);

    $company = Factory::make('\Company', ['id' => 745]);

    $company2 = Factory::make('\Company', ['id' => 987]);

    // Products must be faked because item has an attribute that depends on it
    $product = Factory::make('\Product', ['id' => 12]);

    $product2 = Factory::make('\Product', ['id' => 13]);

    $product3 = Factory::make('\Product', ['id' => 14]);

    $item = Factory::orderItem(array(
        'id'            => 1,
        'order_id'      => 666,
        'company_id'    => 745,
        'product_id'    => 12,
        'subproduct_id' => null,
        'product_name'  => 'ABC 123', 
        'product_code'  => 'abc123dacode',
        'quantity'      => 1, 
        'price'         => 98.72
    ));

    $item->company = $company;

    $item->product = $product;

    $item2 = Factory::orderItem(array(
        'id'            => 2,
        'order_id'      => 666,
        'company_id'    => 745,
        'product_id'    => 13,
        'subproduct_id' => null,
        'product_name'  => 'Xylofoon Jup', 
        'quantity'      => 3, 
        'price'         => 10.44
    ));

    $item2->company = $company;

    $item->product = $product2;

    $item3 = Factory::orderItem(array(
        'id'            => 3,
        'order_id'      => 666,
        'company_id'    => 987,
        'product_id'    => 14,
        'subproduct_id' => null,
        'product_name'  => 'Kleed',
        'quantity'      => 2, 
        'price'         => 74.50
    ));

    $item->product = $product3;

    $item3->company = $company2;

    $items = new Collection([$item, $item2, $item3]);

    $this->order->items = $items;

    $this->invoiceModel = $this->mock('App\Models\Invoice');

    $this->invoiceItemModel = $this->mock('App\Models\InvoiceItem');

    $this->creditNoteModel = $this->mock('App\Models\CreditNote');

    $this->creditNoteItemModel = $this->mock('App\Models\CreditNoteItem');

    $this->invoiceRepo = \App::make('App\Repositories\Eloquent\InvoiceRepository');
}

public function testCreateUserInvoice()
{
    $this->order->status = 'sent';

    $invoiceData = array(
        'order_id'         => $this->order->id,
        'user_id'          => $this->order->user_id,
        'from_name'        => InvoiceRepository::STORESQUARE_NAME,
        'from_address'     => InvoiceRepository::STORESQUARE_ADDRESS,
        'from_postal_code' => InvoiceRepository::STORESQUARE_POSTAL_CODE,
        'from_city'        => InvoiceRepository::STORESQUARE_CITY,
        'from_email'       => InvoiceRepository::STORESQUARE_EMAIL,
        'from_vat'         => InvoiceRepository::STORESQUARE_VAT,
        'to_name'          => $this->order->customer_name,
        'to_address'       => $this->order->customer_invoice_address,
        'to_postal_code'   => $this->order->customer_invoice_postal_code,
        'to_city'          => $this->order->customer_invoice_city,
        'to_email'         => $this->order->customer_email,
        'total'            => $this->order->total
    );

    $invoice = \Mockery::mock('App\Models\Invoice')->makePartial();
    $invoice->fill($invoiceData);

    $builder = \Mockery::mock('Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder');

    $this->invoiceModel->shouldReceive('where')
                       ->with('order_id', $this->order->id)
                       ->andReturn($builder);

    $builder->shouldReceive('whereNotNull')
            ->with('user_id')
            ->andReturn($builder);

    $builder->shouldReceive('get')
            ->andReturn(new Collection([]));

    $this->invoiceModel->shouldReceive('validateException')
                       ->once()
                       ->with($invoiceData);

    $this->invoiceModel->shouldReceive('create')
                       ->once()
                       ->with($invoiceData)
                       ->andReturn($invoice);

    $invoiceItems = [];

    foreach($this->order->items as $item)
    {
        $invoiceItems[] = new InvoiceItem(array(
            'invoice_id'  => $invoice->id,
            'description' => $item->product_code ? $item->product_name . ' (' . $item->product_code . ')' : $item->product_name,
            'quantity'    => $item->quantity,
            'price'       => $item->price
        ));
    }

    $relation = \Mockery::mock('Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany');

    $invoice->shouldReceive('items')
            ->once()
            ->andReturn($relation);

    $relation->shouldReceive('saveMany')
             ->with($invoiceItems);

    $createdInvoice = $this->invoiceRepo->createUserInvoice($this->order);

    $this->assertEquals($invoice, $createdInvoice);
}

public function testCreateUserInvoiceInvalidStatusThrowsException()
{
    $this->order->status = 'payment_received';

    $this->setExpectedException('App\Repositories\Exceptions\InvoiceRepositoryException');

    $this->invoiceRepo->createUserInvoice($this->order);
}

public function testCreateUserInvoiceDuplicateThrowsException()
{
    $this->order->status = 'sent';

    $invoice = Factory::make('App\Models\Invoice', ['id' => 66]);

    $builder = \Mockery::mock('Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder');

    $this->invoiceModel->shouldReceive('where')
                       ->with('order_id', $this->order->id)
                       ->andReturn($builder);

    $builder->shouldReceive('whereNotNull')
            ->with('user_id')
            ->andReturn(\Mockery::self())
            ->shouldReceive('get')
            ->andReturn(new Collection([$invoice]));

    $this->setExpectedException('App\Repositories\Exceptions\InvoiceRepositoryException');

    $this->invoiceRepo->createUserInvoice($this->order);
}
```

Comment: There's no such thing as testing too much... though writing tests just for the sake of it, or writing that extra test, just so you can claim 100% code-coverage is a bit silly IMO. But bottom line: testing _"too much"_ is a real first-world problem. So long as it doesn't slow your build down too much, don't worry about it :)

Comment: Hey thanks. Well I'm trying to adopt TDD from now on.  I can see it's a first-world problem :). But I asked because I read somewhere that you shouldn't test too much of the innards of the method you're testing but just be concerned with the output or required calls. I'm kinda testing all calls. But I'm happy with it for now. And I don't really see a way around it. I need to mock all those calls or the test fails.

Comment: Testing the inner workings can be a sign of testing for the sake of it, or to boast 100% coverage. That's not needed, and it'll just slow the build process down. But testing the computation/processing done in a crucial component of an application just makes sense. If somebody somwhere down the line changes a protected method that is called mid-way between the public call and the return value, I'd like to have unit tests that can point me at the root cause of the problem

Comment: Well that's where I'm uncertain on the topic. What to test exactly. But this repository method is quite crucial as it creates invoices. I think it's good to have tests for it. But it depends mostly on the invoice and invoiceItem model. Calls on these object are required to validate and create the items. So I presume it's logically to have to mock these. On the other hand, if my test where to touch the database, I could check the database in my test to see if the data is there. Is that better? My test has to mock a lot of internal classes. Normally tests shouldn't touch the database I read.

Comment: You _could_ use AspectMock to avoid the actual data provider (the DB) of becomming involved. I've played around with it, but for what I tried to do, the tool needs to mature some more, still. However, it's very common to use `.sql` files in your tests, and use those as a temp DB, just make sure those fixtures or data files contain representative data (both valid and invalid), to cover all eventualities. I like tests with the odd `@expectedException` annotation :)

Comment: I did some more reading quickly :). Also I looked at the core Laravel tests. They seem to have a lot of mocking too. It looks very similar to my test. But I also looked at the Codeception testing framework and they have a `$this->tester->seeRecord()` method to check database values. I think it's up to me to decide what is best. Mocking everything out or let the actual underlying objects do their work and check the db. For now I think it's best to have my unit tests test the unit and not depend on the underlying objects. Although checking the db for the required values seems very useful too :)

Comment: Think I found an acceptable strategy. I'll continue writing my unit tests by mocking everything out as I did here. Later I'll invest some time in writing acceptance tests that check the db for the correct values. I'll use Codeception for this. Thanks for all the info!